# xcodebuild command link libraries

Tags: xcode, linker, xcodebuild

Is there a way to specify iOS libraries to be linked while building an app from command line using xcodebuild command? 
I know we can specify third party frameworks using OTHER_LDFLAGS="..path/to/framework" but since the built in framework paths may vary based on the machine/sdk etc, I'm assuming there could be some better way than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xcodebuild` builds project files, so typically you configure everything in the project rather than passing many configuration parameters. To link built-in frameworks, you just use the Link with Libraries build step and add the frameworks you want. Built-in frameworks should automatically be stored as SDK-relative. (Note that you should basically never use this to link relative-path libraries in your package; it is usually better to use `OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS` for those.)

The linker flag you want if you need it is `-framework <name>`. But you shouldn't need that very often when using `xcodebuild`. It's mostly used when calling `clang` or `ld` directly.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. The reason I want to do this is because, I create a custom framework and I want to integrate this framework along with other required built-in frameworks into a sample app (basically automate and check the read-me that I provide along with the framework). Can you point me to any examples that uses the linker flag option "-framework" ?

Comment: If this is a custom framework that is being built as part of this project (its own xcodeproj is a member of the workspace, or it is a target of the project), then you actually can use the Link Libraries step and that'll work fine (since it knows the dependency). You only need `-framework` if you're shipping a binary framework that would be referenced by a relative path. Then you just add that to `OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS`. I haven't seen that done in any open source projects, so I don't know of any online examples. For a good real-world example of dealing with frameworks, see Adium (adium.im).

Comment: I'm shipping a binary framework. I'll try out OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS and check Adium source too.  I'll post back if I can find an example. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Something like this works for me.  

xcodebuild FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS="../MyFramework/" OTHER_LDFLAGS="/path/to/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework -lz -lc++ -framework CoreTelephony"

Comment: Do you link with `clang` or with `ld`?  On the command line when I do `swiftc foo.swift -v` I see `ld` being invoked for linking. However when I open the build log in Xcode's Report Navigator, under the section for 'Link <FooApp>' I see `clang` being invoked. I see clang being invoked for linking a framework target as well. Is that expected? I thought `clang` doesn't do linking and it only compiles C family language. Why am I not seeing `ld` invoked?

Comment: `clang` handles the linking piece for you. For a very simple C program `clang main.c` is enough to build it and create an executable called `a.out`